# There is some errors in my Matlab code of for-loops. I would like to ask if someone know where is the error

Tags: matlab, for-loop

For a function of 3 variables: f, ksid and rho, I want to search the combination of f and ksid in order to have the minimum peak for the curve y-rho.
I used 3 'for loops' to define the range of the 3 variables.
minH5 is the the value of minimum peak for curve y-rho, p is the index which can help me to find the corresponding value of f and ksid.
The result is different from fitting curve which I drawed to compare. I would appreciate a lot if someone can point out where is the error.

```
clear all
close all
m=0.01;
ksi=0.02;
f1=[];
ksid1=[];
f1=[];
max1f=[];
max1=[];
y1=[];
pe1=[];
H5e=[];

for  ksid=0.1:0.0001:0.12
 for f=0.85:0.0001:0.9
     for e=0.85:0.001:1.4
         y=((f.^2-e.^2).^2+(2.*ksid.*e.*f).^2).^0.5./((-f.^2.*e.^2.*m+(1-e.^2).*(f.^2- 
e.^2)-4.*ksi.*ksid.*f.*e.^2).^2+4.*(ksi.*e.*(f.^2-e.^2)+ksid.*f.*e.*(1-e.^2.*(1+m))).^2).^0.5;
         y1=[y1,y];
     end
     [H5e,pe]=max(y1);
     y1 = [];
     pe1=[pe1,pe];
     max1f=[max1f,H5e];
     f1=[f1,f];
 end
     ksid1=[ksid1,ksid]; 
end

[minH5,p]=min(max1f);
```

Comment: Side remark: Growing vectors inside loops can make your program slower. Consider allocating vectors/arrays in advance, with e.g. `y1=nan([1 123456]);`. (Using `nan()` rather than say `zero()` makes errors usually easier to spot.)

Comment: "The result is different from fitting curve" So what result do you get? What result do you expect?

Comment: "minimum peak for the curve" you don't look for peaks. Your `max` operation is over all values of `y` computed so far, it doesn't identify peaks. The right way to do this would be to sample the whole space, store all values of `y` in an array, then find peaks in that array, then compare these peak's values.

Comment: I've computed your `y`, and I don't see any peaks. Are you sure the equation is correct? And the ranges over which you search?